# Passing list as an argument

Tags: c#, list, reference

I seem to have an unexpected issue with objects' references. There is a draft of what my code does:

```
// file 1
List<A> list1;
List<B> list2 = function(list1);
//file 2
public static List<B> function(List<A> input)
{
    list<B> output = new List<B>();
    for (int i ...)
    {
        output.Add(new B(input[i]));
    {
    return output;
}
// file 1
list1[1].FieldOfAObject = 10; // I change an object from list1
WriteLine(list2[1].objectA.FieldOfAObject); // it is not changed
```

It would seem to me, that as list1 is a class and A is a class and they are passed by a reference, objects of type B created in a `function`and assigned to `list2` should keep a reference on objects of `list1`.

**EDIT**
Real code:

```
public void PrintCylinder(Camera camera, Cylinder cylinder, Bitmap Bitmap, double bitmapWidth, double bitmapHeight, PrintArguments pa)
    {
        ...
        List<AffineCoordinates> verticesToPritOnScreen = new List<AffineCoordinates>(); // out list1
        foreach (var vertex in cylinder.Mesh.MeshVertices)
        {
            AffineCoordinates newVertex = PVM * vertex;
            verticesToPritOnScreen.Add(newVertex); // list1 is being filled here
        }

        List<Face> FaceList = MeshGridGenerator.GenerateCylinderGrid(verticesToPritOnScreen, cylinder.D); // our list2

// CHANGES BENEATH ARE NOT VISIBLE IN FaceList objects
        for (int i = 0; i < verticesToPritOnScreen.Count; ++i)
        {
            // project to NDC
            verticesToPritOnScreen[i] = verticesToPritOnScreen[i] / verticesToPritOnScreen[i].W;
            // project to screen space
            verticesToPritOnScreen[i].X = (verticesToPritOnScreen[i].X + 1) * bitmapWidth / 2;
            verticesToPritOnScreen[i].Y = (verticesToPritOnScreen[i].Y + 1) * bitmapHeight / 2;
            verticesToPritOnScreen[i].Z = (verticesToPritOnScreen[i].Z + 1) / 2;
            verticesToPritOnScreen[i].W = 1;
        }

        ...
    }
// our function (from MeshGridGenerator class)
public static List<Face> GenerateCylinderGrid(List<AffineCoordinates> vertices, int D)
    {
        List<Face> FaceList = new List<Face>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= D; ++i)
        {
            // upper base
            FaceList.Add(new Face(vertices[0], vertices[i], vertices[i % D + 1]));
            // bottom base
            FaceList.Add(new Face(vertices[vertices.Count - 1], vertices[i % D + 1 + D], vertices[i + D]));
            // side wall's upper triangle
            FaceList.Add(new Face(vertices[i], vertices[i + D], vertices[i % D + 1]));
            // side wall's bottom triangle
            FaceList.Add(new Face(vertices[i % D + 1], vertices[i + D], vertices[i % D + 1 + D]));
        }

        return FaceList;
    }
// our B class
public class Face
{
    public AffineCoordinates[] vertices;

    public bool AreVerticesClockwise
    {
        get
        {
            double sum = 0.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            {
                sum += (vertices[(i + 1) % 3].X - vertices[i].X) * (vertices[(i + 1) % 3].Y + vertices[i].Y);
            }
            return sum < 0;
        }
    }

    public Face(params AffineCoordinates[] ver)
    {
        vertices = new AffineCoordinates[3];
        vertices[0] = ver[0];
        vertices[1] = ver[1];
        vertices[2] = ver[2];
    }
}
```

I know it is plenty of ode, that's why I didn't want to post it.

Comment: Can you show the constructor for B?

Comment: Nobody here can guess how that `B` type behaves, so if you want help figuring out why it doesn't behave as you expected you will have to post it. Also, post *real* code, since the code doesn't compile (incomplete for definition, incorrectly placed braces) etc. it makes it hard to believe this is even a cut-down version of your real code. If you want help with your actual code, post your actual code, or *even better*, post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

This code prints '20' which is what I think you're after?

```
 public class A
 {
      public int Value;
 }

 public class B
 {
      public A objectA;
      public B(A obj)
      {
            objectA = obj;
      }
 }
 class Program
 {
      public static List<B> function(List<A> input)
      {
            List<B> output = new List<B>();
            foreach  (var i in input)
            {
                 output.Add(new B(i));
            }
            return output;
      }
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
            List<A> listA = new List<A>();
            listA.Add(new A { Value = 10 });
            List<B> listB = function(listA);
            listA[0].Value = 20;
            Console.WriteLine(listB[0].objectA.Value);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Why are you instantiating `listB` to replace it with `function(listA)`? Also, `A.Value` and `B.objectA` should both be properties, not fields

Comment: The point of the code is to demonstrate that B contains a reference to A which is the problem the OP is having. It can be improved in a lot of ways... :)

Comment: If you demonstrate bad practices to a person who's just learning, they'll learn bad practices. I've seen way too many times production code with things like `a = new List<T>(); a = GetData();`

Comment: Feel free to post a better answer

Comment: @HansKilian your code is a simpler version of what I have and I have no idea why my code fails.